# Calculating the coefficient $c_0$

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

There is an exercise to sketch the function
$f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ on the interval $0<x<1$
and then find the complex Fourier series.
I tried doing it in two ways:

Firstly, I got $L=1/2$ and while calculating $a_0$ by using
$$
a_0=\frac1{2L}\int_{0}^{1} \sin (\pi x)\,dx,
$$
I got its value to be $2/\pi$.

Secondly I tried to calculate the $c_n$ directly. But while calculating the complex coefficient $c_0$ directly by using
$$
c_0=\frac1{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}\sin (\pi x)\,dx,
$$
I got its value to be $0$.

This confused me a lot as $a_0$  and $c_0$ should be equal.

I know I made a mistake somewhere and there is some gap in my understanding. Please help.

Comment: The second formula is assuming your interval is symmetric around $0$.   If you want to use that integral you will have to shift your function's values in the $\frac {-1} 2$ to $0$ region to be the same as the values of the function in the $\frac 1 2$ to $1$ range

Comment: Thank you so much. It is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier coefficients $c_n$ of the complex representation is given by

$$
c_n=\frac{1}{T}\int^\frac{T}{2}_{-\frac{T}{2}}f(t)e^{in\omega _0t}dt
$$
or

$$
c_n=\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0f(t)e^{in\omega _0t}dt
$$ (notice the integration limits)

This is indeed equal to $a_0$ if you evaluate the integral within $(0,1)$ as required.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clear.